# Is this set up possible to enable file download on a ajax call in PHP?

Tags: php, ajax

I am by no means a web developer. I have worked on GWT a little bit. We used to have this kind of set up there. Since everything there is ajax, every time we would make a server RPC call, we would show a progress bar, which we would close in callback of rpc/ajax when response would come back.

Now I working on a tool which tries to do it in PHP(which I am still learning). I have got a set up which looks like this,

> 1: There is html form with a few fields in it. I actually need a file upload options here, but for example's sake, let's just say there are two text fields.
>
> 2: When the user submits the forms. I want to make a post ajax call to say test.php and in the mean time, show a progress bar appearing(basically blocking the whole page, but not refreshing page also). When the ajax response comes, I will close the progress bar.
>
> 3: Now, if the server is returning some text, it is easy to handle that, I can handle it in the ajax callback with document.getElementById. But in my case what I do is that, I want to do some processing server side with post parameters, create a text file and return it. And then come back to client side and close the progress.

I have  written a sample script which returns a file by setting the headers

> header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
> header('Content-Type: text/csv');
> header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);

So this php file is working fine independently, when I open it in browser, it throws a download link. When I try to call it through the ajax request, it does not return anything.

Can anyone please tell me if this approach is incorrect?

Comment: _Because_ AJAX means a request in the background, there is no possibility to get the response handled by anything else than the script that initiated the request – and therefor no download/“save as” dialog will pop up, since it is your script’s responsibility to handle the response. Workarounds are either to create a Data URI in the script and assign that to `location.href` to trigger a download dialog, or to have the server output the actual download data on a _second_ request made the “normal” way (initiated by pointing `location.href` to a URL that makes the server deliver the data).

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    window.open("filedownload.php, '_self', false);
</script>
```

will prompt the user to download the file without navigating to a new page.

The browser will handle the download progress display. This is the experience the user will be familiar with.

If you want the file to download on completion of an ajax request add the above code to the `XMLHttpRequest` callback